# Canon MG 2220 scanner not working in Ubuntu Mate 18.04

Tags: scanner

I am trying to get my scanner working for a Canon MG 2220 printer/scanner for Ubuntu Mate 18.04.

Files came from https://www.canonupdates.com/canon-pixma-mg2220-driver-software-for-windows-mac-linux/

Scanner works fine in 16.04.

When installing scangearmp-common_2.00-1_amd64.deb, I get

```
 Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libpng12-0(>=1.2.8rel)
```

For scangearmp-mg2200series_2.00-1_amd64.deb

```
 Error: Dependency is not satisfiable:scangearmp-common(<=1.00)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should download [`libpng12`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=libpng12-0) from previous supported Ubuntu version:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
```

Then continue as you did before.

---

I recommend to use official [Canon site with drivers](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mg_series/pixma_mg2240.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=Linux%20(64-bit)). The do the following steps (download, install dependencies and Canon drivers):

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/7/0100004697/01/scangearmp-mg2200series-2.00-1-deb.tar.gz
tar -xf scangearmp-mg2200series-2.00-1-deb.tar.gz
sudo apt-get install libpango1.0-0 libpangox-1.0-0 libusb-0.1-4
sudo sh install.sh
```

Comment: I followed your directions. I thought deb files when run would do the installation? I did run the install.sh and got

Comment: You can proceed with your deb-files. But do not forget to install libpng12 manually.

Comment: Working like a champ now. :-)